# Interesting patterns related to the sums of the remainders of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, conjectures, semiprimes

Let us define,
$$r(b)=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{b-1}{2} \rfloor} (b \bmod{k})$$

After reading the posts [Surprising fact about a certain number-theoretic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582249/surprising-fact-about-a-certain-number-theoretic-function) and [Do primes have special sums...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582057/do-primes-have-special-sums-in-some-well-defined-sense-of-remainders-or-quotie?noredirect=1&lq=1) I decided to play around with the $r(b)$ function and after performing some computations using PARI/GP, I found some very interesting patterns.

1. $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=0$ when $a\in {2, 3}$ for any $n\in \Bbb{N}$. (Proved by user Haran in the first post)
2. For fixed $a$ and any $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is either always positive or always negative when $a$ is not of the form $2p$ or $3q$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p\gt 3, q\gt 7$.
3. For fixed $a$, $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is initially postive and then becomes negative as $n\in \Bbb{N}$ increases when $a$ is the form of $2p$ or $3q$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p\gt 3, q\gt 7$.
4. If $a \notin \{2p, 3p\}$ is prime or semiprime then $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is positive for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$. (edit)

What is the reason for these weird characteristics or $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$? I would really appreciate if someone could prove/disprove any of the last 3 observations.

Here is some of the initial data from where I made my observations. The first column gives the $a$ values, the second gives the $n$ values, and the third gives the corresponding values of $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$.

```
1 1 0
1 2 0
1 3 0
1 4 0
1 5 0
2 1 0
2 2 0
2 3 0
2 4 0
2 5 0
3 1 0
3 2 0
3 3 0
3 4 0
3 5 0
4 1 0
4 2 0
4 3 0
4 4 0
4 5 0
5 1 1
5 2 6
5 3 31
5 4 156
5 5 781
6 1 -1
6 2 -20
6 3 -169
6 4 -1160
6 5 -7381
7 1 2
7 2 16
7 3 114
7 4 800
7 5 5602
8 1 0
8 2 0
8 3 0
8 4 0
8 5 0
9 1 0
9 2 0
9 3 0
9 4 0
9 5 0
10 1 1
10 2 -18
10 3 -341
10 4 -4212
10 5 -46079
11 1 4
11 2 48
11 3 532
11 4 5856
11 5 64420
12 1 -5
12 2 -116
12 3 -1625
12 4 -20360
12 5 -247445
13 1 5
13 2 70
13 3 915
13 4 11900
13 5 154705
14 1 3
14 2 -8
14 3 -513
14 4 -10000
14 5 -159657
15 1 -2
15 2 -66
15 3 -1178
15 4 -18564
15 5 -282722
16 1 0
16 2 0
16 3 0
16 4 0
16 5 0
17 1 7
17 2 126
17 3 2149
17 4 36540
17 5 621187
18 1 -4
18 2 -200
18 3 -4732
18 4 -95120
18 5 -1800964
19 1 8
19 2 160
19 3 3048
19 4 57920
19 5 1100488
20 1 -3
20 2 -162
20 3 -3813
20 4 -79092
20 5 -1595583
21 1 -1
21 2 -80
21 3 -2109
21 4 -47200
21 5 -1011161
22 1 7
22 2 36
22 3 -665
22 4 -30744
22 5 -853565
23 1 10
23 2 240
23 3 5530
23 4 127200
23 5 2925610
24 1 -13
24 2 -500
24 3 -13273
24 4 -327560
24 5 -7929493
25 1 6
25 2 156
25 3 3906
25 4 97656
25 5 2441406
26 1 9
26 2 70
26 3 -549
26 4 -45220
26 5 -1577991
27 1 0
27 2 0
27 3 0
27 4 0
27 5 0
28 1 -1
28 2 -200
28 3 -6897
28 4 -202000
28 5 -5716841
29 1 13
29 2 390
29 3 11323
29 4 328380
29 5 9523033
30 1 -13
30 2 -1022
30 3 -39601
30 4 -1309532
30 5 -40972393
31 1 14
31 2 448
31 3 13902
31 4 430976
31 5 13360270
32 1 0
32 2 0
32 3 0
32 4 0
32 5 0
33 1 1
33 2 -96
33 3 -4655
33 4 -169824
33 5 -5781695
```

Comment: Interesting question. Do you know if $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ always strictly increases or decreases when $a$ is not of the form $2p$ or $3q$?

Comment: @Mr.Matho no, that is a nice question to ask too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ :
$$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=
\begin{cases}
2a^n-1-\sigma(a^n)  & \text{if $2 \mid a$} \\
\frac{3a^n-1}{2}-\sigma(a^n) & \text{if $2 \nmid a$}
\end{cases}$$

---

### Question $1$

We have:
$$r(2^n)-r(2^n-1)=2(2^n)-1-\sigma(2^n)=2^{n+1}-1-(2^{n+1}-1)=0$$
$$r(3^n)-r(3^n-1)=\frac{3(3^n)-1}{2}-\sigma(3^n)=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}-\bigg(\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}\bigg)=0$$
This solves Question $1$.

---

### Question $2$

As mathlove points out, this is false. $110$ is a counterexample. A weaker version of this can be proven:

> All values of $a$ which are not powers of $2$ or powers of $3$ lead to $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ eventually being all positive or all negative.

I personally feel that this is **the heart of the problem**. We have:
$$a=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i} \implies \sigma(a^n)=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{a_in+1}-1}{p_i-1}$$
This gives:
$$\frac{\sigma(a^n)}{a^n}=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i-(1/p_i^{a_in})}{p_i-1} \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(a^n)}{a^n}=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}=c_a$$

Now, as $n$ gets large, we can see that $\frac{\sigma(a^n)}{a^n} \to c_a$ which is a constant for $a$. We know:
$$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=
\begin{cases}
2a^n-1-\sigma(a^n)  & \text{if $2 \mid a$} \\
\frac{3a^n-1}{2}-\sigma(a^n) & \text{if $2 \nmid a$}
\end{cases}
$$
This gives:
$$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1) \sim 
\begin{cases}
2a^n-c_a a^n  & \text{if $2 \mid a$} \\
\frac{3}{2}a^n-c_aa^n & \text{if $2 \nmid a$}
\end{cases}
$$

It is clear that this value will eventually become all positive or all negative (which is what we are required to show) when $c_a \neq 2$ and $c_a \neq \frac{3}{2}$.

If $c_a=2$, we have:
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}=2$$
Clearly, we need an even prime, so let $p_1=1$. Then:
$$\prod_{i=2}^k \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}=1$$
But this forces there to be no other primes, since $\frac{p_i}{p_i-1}>1$ for all primes. Since $2$ is the only prime divisor of $a$, $a$ must be a power of $2$ (which is one of the exceptions).

The same argument works for $\frac{3}{2}$ where $p_1=3$ is forced to be the only prime, giving powers of $3$ as an exception. Thus, these are the only exceptions (and we also know that in these cases, the difference is always zero). Hence, we have proven the required.

Thus, we have proven the following **lemma**-

> Define: $$c_a=\prod_{p \mid a} \frac{p}{p-1}$$
>
> The difference $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is-
>
> - eventually all negative, if $c_a>2$.
> - all $0$, if $c_a=2$ (which only happens for $a=2^t$).
> - eventually all negative, if $c_a>1.5$ and $a$ is odd.
> - all $0$, if $c_a=1.5$ (which only happens for $a=3^t$).
> - eventually all positive, if $1.5>c_a$.0

---

### Question $3$

Let $a=2p \space (p>3)$. Then:
$$c_a=\frac{2}{1} \cdot \frac{p}{p-1} > 2$$
Thus, $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is eventually all negative (from lemma). At $n=1$,
$$r(a)-r(a-1)=4p-1-\sigma(2p)=p-4>0$$
Thus, there is an eventual transition from positive to negative.

Let $a=3q \space (q>7)$. Then:
$$c_a=\frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{q}{q-1} > \frac{3}{2}$$
Also, $a$ is odd. Thus, $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is eventually all negative (from lemma). At $n=1$,
$$r(a)-r(a-1)=\frac{9q-1}{2} - \sigma(3q) = \frac{q-9}{2}>0$$
Thus, there is an eventual transition from positive to negative.

---

### Question $4$

We are to simply substitute $a=p$, $a=p^2$ and $a=pq$.

If $a=p$,
$$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=\frac{3p^n-1}{2}-\sigma(p^n)=\frac{3p^n-1}{2}-\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}>0$$

If $a=p^2$,
$$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=\frac{3p^{2n}-1}{2}-\sigma(p^{2n})=\frac{3p^{2n}-1}{2}-\frac{p^{2n+1}-1}{p-1}>0$$

If $a=pq$,
$$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=\frac{3p^nq^n-1}{2}-\sigma(p^nq^n)=\frac{3p^nq^n-1}{2}-\bigg( \frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1} \cdot \frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1} \bigg)>0$$

All of these can be shown by expanding (strenuous but straightforward). This completes all $4$ problems.

Comment: +1 I really like how you covered all the different cases in your lemma for question 2

Answer (score 2):

Conjecture 2 is false, and conjecture 3 and 4 (edit) are true.

---

[Haran's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3582676/78967) to the question [Surprising fact about a certain number-theoretic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3582249/surprising-fact-about-a-certain-number-theoretic-function) shows that
$$r(b+1)-r(b)=\begin{cases}2b+1-\sigma(b+1)&\text{if $b$ is odd}\\\\\frac{3b+2}{2}-\sigma(b+1)&\text{if $b$ is even}\end{cases}$$

So, setting $b=a^n-1$, we can have
$$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=\begin{cases}2a^n-1-\sigma(a^n)&\text{if $a$ is even}\\\\\frac{3a^n-1}{2}-\sigma(a^n)&\text{if $a$ is odd}\end{cases}$$

> 3. For fixed $a$, $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is initially postive and then becomes negative as $n\in \Bbb{N}$ increases when $a$ is the form of $2p$ or $3q$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p\gt 3, q\gt 7$.

This is true.

$$\begin{align}r((2p)^n)-r((2p)^n-1)&=2(2p)^n-1-\sigma(2^n)\sigma(p^n)
\\\\&=2^{n+1}p^n-1-(2^{n+1}-1)\cdot\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}
\\\\&=\frac{(2^{n+1}p^n-1)(p-1)-(2^{n+1}-1)(p^{n+1}-1)}{p-1}
\\\\&=\frac{(p^n-1)(p-2^{n+1})}{p-1}\end{align}$$
which is initially postive and then becomes negative as $n\in \Bbb{N}$ increases.

$$\begin{align}r((3q)^n)-r((3q)^n-1)&=\frac{3(3q)^n-1}{2}-\sigma(3^n)\sigma(q^n)
\\\\&=\frac{3^{n+1}q^{n}-1}{2}-\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2}\cdot\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}
\\\\&=\frac{(q-3^{n+1})(q^n-1)}{2(q-1)}\end{align}$$
which is initially postive and then becomes negative as $n\in \Bbb{N}$ increases.

> 4. If $a$ is prime or semiprime then $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is positive for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

This is not true. Counterexamples are $a=2,3$ for which $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=0$ for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

It is true that if $a\gt 3$ is a prime, then $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is positive for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$ since

$$\begin{align}r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)&=\frac{3a^n-1}{2}-\sigma(a^n)
\\\\&=\frac{3a^n-1}{2}-\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}
\\\\&=\frac{(a-3)(a^n-1)}{2(a-1)}\end{align}$$

It is not true that if $a$ is a semiprime, then $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is positive for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$.

A counterexample is $(a,n)=(10,2)$ for which we get
$$r(10^2)-r(10^2-1)=2\cdot 10^2-1-\sigma(10^2)=-18$$

---

**Added** :

> 4. If $a \notin \{2p, 3p\}$ is prime or semiprime then $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is positive for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$. (edit)

This is true.

If $a=pq$ where $p,q$ are odd primes such that $5\le p\lt q$, then we get
$$\begin{align}&r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)
\\\\&=\frac{3(pq)^n-1}{2}-\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}\cdot\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}
\\\\&=\frac{p^nq^n((p-3)(q-3)-6)+2p^{n+1}+q(2q^{n}-p)+p+q-3}{2(p-1)(q-1)}\gt 0\end{align}$$

If $a=p^2$ where $p\ge 5$ is a prime, then $$r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)=\frac{p(p^{2n-1}(p-3)-1)+3}{2(p-1)}\gt 0$$

> 2. For fixed $a$ and any $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $r(a^n)-r(a^n-1)$ is either always positive or always negative when $a$ is not of the form $2p$ or $3q$ where $p,q$ are prime and $p\gt 3, q\gt 7$.

This is false.

A counterexample is $a=2\cdot 5\cdot 11=110$ since
$$r(110^1)-r(110^1-1)=2\cdot 110^1-1-\sigma(110^1)=3\gt 0$$
$$r(110^2)-r(110^2-1)=2\cdot 110^2-1-\sigma(110^2)=-4662\lt 0$$

---

**Conclusion** :

- Conjecture 2 is false. (A counterexample is $a=2\cdot 5\cdot 11=110$.)
- Conjecture 3 is true.
- Conjecture 4 (edit) is true.

Comment: oops I forgot to add the $a \notin {2p, 3p}$ condition to 4. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Mathphile : Finally I got a counterexample to conjecture 2. See the added part.